# ASP.NET WebService to receive calls from multiple threads

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, web-services, function-calls

Let's say you have a bunch of threads that all call into the same ASP.NET webservice from a website.  I wondered if anyone knows how these calls would get handled at the webservice site?  Is all synchronization taken care of?  Do these calls just get called in order?

Can anyone shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

They're handled by the web server just like any other web request. You don't need any synchronization you wouldn't need in a regular website (and if you need it, performance will be the first to die under load). There are no guarantees of order. The requests are served as they come and the responses returned as they complete.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for each call there is a new service created. If you have access to any database or filesystem. you need to handle. In any other way you don't need to care about it. If you use SQL or MySQL multithreading should be supportable too.
[Concurrent transactions and multi-threaded database access in embedded SQL applications](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.embed.doc/doc/c0006107.htm)

Comment: Do you have a technical reference where this comes from "As far as I know for each call there is a new service created" ?